# Deserialize Fails to populate elements in the object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a few questions about deserializing an xml file into an object that has been bothering me for almost two days. I appreciate any help anyone can offer!

I used xsd.exe to generate c# classes from the schema files. I then used XMLExplorer to create a sample XML file. Is it a correct assumption that if I save that sample file, unchanged, with the sample text values, and deserialize it into the appropriate c# class, that it "should" read the values and put them into the appropriate objects???

Does the XMLDeserializer REQUIRE that all elements be present in the XML file or can an XML file contain missing elements and still be deserialized correctly (by, for instance, putting null values in missing properties)???

I've read that XMLSerializer only checks for three errors and I've got those resolved by tagging the xmlroot and removing a broken URL. My code runs, but I'm getting nulls for "InvokingBusinessActivity" and "Passenger" and other properties.

Here's my deserialization code.

```
IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQ localIataReq = new IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQ();

                XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(localIataReq.GetType());

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Airports\\Projects_Current\\Multi-channel\\Dev\\Integration\\MCUniversalBagDropAPITester\\IataXmlSchemas\\Test Xml Files\\PassengerIdentifyRequest.xml");
                XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
                xRoot.ElementName = "IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQ";
                xRoot.IsNullable = false;

                localIataReq = (IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQ)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
                reader.Close();
```

here's my class that was generate from XSD. This is trimmed down because it is about 1000 lines:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.0.30319.1.
// 
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://www.iata.org/IATA/2007/00")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQ", IsNullable = false)] /* I commented out and obfuscated defective Namespace="http://ww w.iat a.org/IATA/2007/00",*/
public partial class IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQ
{

    private SourceType[] originatorField;

    private BusinessActivityType invokingBusinessActivityField;

    private IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQPassenger passengerField;

    private string echoTokenField;

    private System.DateTime timeStampField;

    private bool timeStampFieldSpecified;

    private IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQTarget targetField;

    private decimal versionField;

    private string transactionIdentifierField;

    private string sequenceNmbrField;

    private IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQTransactionStatusCode transactionStatusCodeField;

    private bool transactionStatusCodeFieldSpecified;

    private bool retransmissionIndicatorField;

    private bool retransmissionIndicatorFieldSpecified;

    private string correlationIDField;

    private bool asynchronousAllowedIndField;

    private bool asynchronousAllowedIndFieldSpecified;

    public IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQ() {
        this.targetField = IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQTarget.Production;
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Source", IsNullable=false)]
    public SourceType[] Originator {
        get {
            return this.originatorField;
        }
        set {
            this.originatorField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public BusinessActivityType InvokingBusinessActivity {
        get {
            return this.invokingBusinessActivityField;
        }
        set {
            this.invokingBusinessActivityField = value;
        }
    }
```

ETC......

Here's the test file that was created by VS2010 XMLSchema Explorer. For simplicity, duplicate elements of "complex type" were removed. The broken URL was also removed and I added the xml version to the top to fix serialization issues.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQ>
  <!--  EchoToken="EchoToken1" TimeStamp="1900-01-01T01:01:01-06:00" Target="Production" Version="1" TransactionIdentifier="TransactionIdentifier1" SequenceNmbr="32" TransactionStatusCode="Start" PrimaryLangID="en" AltLangID="en" RetransmissionIndicator="true" CorrelationID="CorrelationID1" AsynchronousAllowedInd="true" xmlns="ht tp: // www . iata.org/IATA/2007/00" -->
  <Originator>
  <Source AgentSine="AgentSine1" PseudoCityCode="PseudoCityCode1" ISOCountry="ISOCountry1" ISOCurrency="ISOCurrency1" AgentDutyCode="AgentDutyCode1" AirlineVendorID="AirlineVendorID1" AirportCode="AirportCode1" FirstDepartPoint="Fi1" ERSP_UserID="ERSP_UserID1" TerminalID="TerminalID1">
    <RequestorID MessagePassword="MessagePassword1" URL="http://uri1" Type="Type1" Instance="Instance1" ID="ID1" ID_Context="ID_Context1">
      <CompanyName CompanyShortName="CompanyShortName1" TravelSector="TravelSector1" Code="Code1" CodeContext="CodeContext1">CompanyName1</CompanyName>
    </RequestorID>
    <Position Latitude="Latitude1" Longitude="Longitude1" Altitude="Altitude1" AltitudeUnitOfMeasureCode="AltitudeUnitOfMeasureCode1" />
    <BookingChannel Type="Type1" Primary="true">
      <CompanyName CompanyShortName="CompanyShortName1" TravelSector="TravelSector1" Code="Code1" CodeContext="CodeContext1">CompanyName1</CompanyName>
    </BookingChannel>
  </Source>
  </Originator>
  <InvokingBusinessActivity Code="06">Baggage Processing</InvokingBusinessActivity>
  <Passenger>
    <GUID>GUID1</GUID>
    <NativeID>NativeID1</NativeID>
    <Name ShareSynchInd="Yes" ShareMarketInd="Yes" NameType="NameType1">
      <NamePrefix>NamePrefix1</NamePrefix>
      <NamePrefix>NamePrefix2</NamePrefix>
      <NamePrefix>NamePrefix3</NamePrefix>
      <GivenName>GivenName1</GivenName>
      <GivenName>GivenName2</GivenName>
      <GivenName>GivenName3</GivenName>
      <MiddleName>MiddleName1</MiddleName>
      <MiddleName>MiddleName2</MiddleName>
      <MiddleName>MiddleName3</MiddleName>
      <SurnamePrefix>SurnamePrefix1</SurnamePrefix>
      <Surname>Surname1</Surname>
      <NameSuffix>NameSuffix1</NameSuffix>
      <NameSuffix>NameSuffix2</NameSuffix>
      <NameSuffix>NameSuffix3</NameSuffix>
      <NameTitle>NameTitle1</NameTitle>
      <NameTitle>NameTitle2</NameTitle>
      <NameTitle>NameTitle3</NameTitle>
    </Name>
    <CustomerLoyalty ShareSynchInd="Yes" ShareMarketInd="Yes" ProgramID="ProgramID1" MembershipID="MembershipID1" TravelSector="TravelSector1" LoyalLevel="LoyalLevel1" SingleVendorInd="SingleVndr" SignupDate="1900-01-01" EffectiveDate="1900-01-01" ExpireDate="1900-01-01" RPH="RPH1" VendorCode="VendorC1 VendorC2 VendorC3 " />
    <CustomerLoyalty ShareSynchInd="No" ShareMarketInd="No" ProgramID="ProgramID2" MembershipID="MembershipID2" TravelSector="TravelSector2" LoyalLevel="LoyalLevel2" SingleVendorInd="Alliance" SignupDate="0001-01-01" EffectiveDate="0001-01-01" ExpireDate="0001-01-01" RPH="RPH2" VendorCode="VendorC4 VendorC5 VendorC6 " />
    <BoardingPass>
      <ForIndividualAirlineUse>ForIndividualAirlineUse1</ForIndividualAirlineUse>
      <DigitalSignature Type="1">DigitalSignature1</DigitalSignature>
    </BoardingPass>
    <Segment>
      <PNR URL="http://uri1" Type="Type1" Instance="Instance1" ID="ID1" ID_Context="ID_Context1" />
      <NativeID>NativeID1</NativeID>
      <Flight>
        <NativeID>NativeID1</NativeID>
        <OperatingCarrier>Op1</OperatingCarrier>
        <FlightNumber>FlightNumber1</FlightNumber>
        <OperationalSuffix>OperationalSuffix1</OperationalSuffix>
        <MarketingCarrier>Ma1</MarketingCarrier>
        <ScheduledDateOfDeparture>1900-01-01</ScheduledDateOfDeparture>
        <ScheduledTimeOfDeparture>01:01:01</ScheduledTimeOfDeparture>
        <ScheduledDateOfArrival>1900-01-01</ScheduledDateOfArrival>
        <ScheduledTimeOfArrival>01:01:01</ScheduledTimeOfArrival>
      </Flight>
      <DepartureAirport>
        <AirportCode>Air1</AirportCode>
        <SourceIndicator>1</SourceIndicator>
      </DepartureAirport>
      <ArrivalAirport>
        <AirportCode>Air1</AirportCode>
        <SourceIndicator>1</SourceIndicator>
      </ArrivalAirport>
      <Cabin>Cabin1</Cabin>
      <SeatNumber>SeatNumber1</SeatNumber>
      <CheckInSequenceNumber>Chec1</CheckInSequenceNumber>
    </Segment>   
  </Passenger>
</IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQ>
```

I'm doing something wrong and I'm not certain exactly what!!! Can someone please advise???

Comment: There is No Need for spamming "?" & "!" in your post.

Comment: Okay. Weird. I created a whole new project on a different development machine and ran through the entire process with all clean XSD->XS and XSD->Sample XML and this code works fine. SO I guess I delete this question or someone can post an answer along the lines of "start over." I suspect that VS2010 kept references to earlier incarnations of the classes, or referenced wrong versions in backup folders. (This actually does happen with older VS versions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below.  I did some spot checking for errors, but there still may be some issue.  I read XML from a different filename so you need to go back to your original filename.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQ localIataReq = new IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQ();

            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(localIataReq.GetType());

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
            xRoot.ElementName = "IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQ";
            xRoot.IsNullable = false;

            localIataReq = (IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQ)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQ));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\test1.xml");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, localIataReq);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQ")]
    public partial class IATA_PassengerConformanceIdentifyRQ
    {
        [XmlElement("Originator")]
        public Originator  originator { get; set;}

        [XmlElement("InvokingBusinessActivity")]
        public InvokingBusinessActivity invokingBusinessActivity { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Passenger")]
        public Passenger passenger { get; set; }

    }


    [XmlRoot("Originator")]
    public partial class Originator
    {
        [XmlElement("Source")]
        public Source source { get; set;}

    }

    [XmlRoot("Source")]
    public class Source 
    {
        [XmlAttribute("AgentSine")]
        public string agentSine { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("PseudoCityCode")]
        public string pseudoCityCode { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("ISOCountry")]
        public string iSOCountry { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("ISOCurrency")]
        public string iSOCurrency { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("AgentDutyCode")]
        public string agentDutyCode { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("AirlineVendorID")]
        public string airlineVendorID { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("AirportCode")]
        public string airportCode { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("FirstDepartPoint")]
        public string firstDepartPoint { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("ERSP_UserID")]
        public string eRSP_UserID { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("TerminalID")]
        public string terminalID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("RequestorID")]
        public RequestorID requestorID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Position")]
        public Position position { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("BookingChannel")]
        public BookingChannel bookingChannel { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot("RequestorID")]
    public class RequestorID
    {
        [XmlAttribute("MessagePassword")]
        public string messagePassword { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("URL")]
        public string url { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Type")]
        public string _type { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Instance")]
        public string instance { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("ID")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("ID_Context")]
        public string id_Context { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot("Position")]
    public partial class Position
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Latitude")]
        public string latitude { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Longitude")]
        public string longitude { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Altitude")]
        public string altitude { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("AltitudeUnitOfMeasureCode")]
        public string altitudeUnitOfMeasureCode { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot("BookingChannel")]
    public class BookingChannel
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Type")]
        public string _type { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Primary")]
        public Boolean primary { get; set; }

       [XmlElement("CompanyName")]
        public CompanyName companyName { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("CompanyName")]
    public class CompanyName
    {
        [XmlAttribute("CompanyShortName")]
        public string companyShortName { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("TravelSector")]
        public string travelSector { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Code")]
        public string code { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("CodeContext")]
        public string codeContext { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }


    [XmlRoot("InvokingBusinessActivity")]
    public class InvokingBusinessActivity
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Code")]
        public string code { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string value { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot("Passenger")]
    public class Passenger
    {
        [XmlElement("GUID")]
        public Value guid { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("NativeID")]
        public Value nativeID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public Name  name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("CustomerLoyalty")]
        public List<CustomerLoyalty> customerLoyalty { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("BoardingPass")]
        public BoardingPass boardingPass { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Segment")]
        public Segment segment { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string value { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot("Name")]
    public class Name
    {
        [XmlAttribute("ShareSynchInd")]
        public string shareSynchInd { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("ShareMarketInd")]
        public string shareMarketInd { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("NameType")]
        public string NameType { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("NamePrefix")]
        public List<string> namePrefix { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("GivenName")]
        public List<string> givenName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("MiddleName")]
        public List<string> middleName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("SurnamePrefix")]
        public List<string> surnamePrefix { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Surname")]
        public List<string> surname { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("NameSuffix")]
        public string nameSuffix { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("NameTitle")]
        public string nameTitle { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot("CustomerLoyalty")]
    public class CustomerLoyalty
    {
        [XmlAttribute("ShareSynchInd")]
        public string shareSynchInd { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("ShareMarketInd")]
        public string shareMarketInd { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("ProgramID")]
        public string programID { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("MembershipID")]
        public string membershipID { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("TravelSector")]
        public string travelSector { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("LoyalLevel")]
        public string loyalLevel { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("SingleVendorInd")]
        public string singleVendorInd { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("SignupDate")]
        public DateTime  signupDate { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("EffectiveDate")]
        public DateTime effectiveDate { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("ExpireDate")]
        public DateTime expireDate { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("RPH")]
        public string rph { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("VendorCode")]
        public string vendorCode { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot("BoardingPass")]
    public class BoardingPass
    {
        [XmlElement("ForIndividualAirlineUse")]
        public string forIndividualAirlineUse { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("DigitalSignature")]
        public DigitalSignature digitalSignature { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("DigitalSignature")]
    public class DigitalSignature
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Type")]
        public int _type { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Segment")]
    public class Segment
    {
        [XmlElement("PNR")]
        public PNR pnr { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("NativeID")]
        public string nativeID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Flight")]
        public Flight flight { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("DepartureAirport")]
        public Airport departureAirport { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ArrivalAirport")]
        public Airport arrivalAirport { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Cabin")]
        public string cabin { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("SeatNumber")]
        public string seatNumber { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("CheckInSequenceNumber")]
        public string checkInSequenceNumber { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot("PNR")]
    public class PNR
    {
        [XmlAttribute("URL")]
        public string url { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Type")]
        public string _type { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Instance")]
        public string Instance { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("ID")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("ID_Context")]
        public string id_Context { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot("Flight")]
    public class Flight
    {
        [XmlElement("NativeID")]
        public string nativeID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("OperatingCarrier")]
        public string operatingCarrier { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("FlightNumber")]
        public string flightNumber { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("OperationalSuffix")]
        public string operationalSuffix { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("MarketingCarrier")]
        public string marketingCarrier { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ScheduledDateOfDeparture")]
        public DateTime scheduledDateOfDeparture { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ScheduledTimeOfDeparture")]
        public DateTime scheduledTimeOfDeparture { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ScheduledDateOfArrival")]
        public DateTime scheduledDateOfArrival { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ScheduledTimeOfArrival")]
        public DateTime scheduledTimeOfArrival { get; set; }
    }

    public class Airport
    {
        [XmlElement("AirportCode")]
        public string airportCode { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("SourceIndicator")]
        public int sourceIndicator { get; set; }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Weird. I created a whole new project on a different development machine and ran through the entire process with all clean XSD->CS and XSD->Sample XML and this code works fine. SO I guess I delete this question or someone can post an answer along the lines of "start over." The only step I know for certain that was different happened when I dragged the header tag from the XMLSchemaExplorer to the designer worksurface instead of the IATA_PASSENGERCONFORMANCEIDENTIFYRQ element. That generated a giant tree of branches, rather than the single node. This could have caused the issue BUT something else that might have happened:  I suspect VS2010 on the older project kept references to earlier incarnations of the classes, or referenced wrong versions in backup folders. (This actually does happen with older VS versions.)